# How can I shorten this python code?

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

Here is the code which I want to shorten.

```
n=input()
while n:
 s=raw_input()
 x,r,g,b=(int(x) for x in s.split())
 a=x/r%2
 c=x/g%2
 d=x/b%2
 r=((a*10+c)*10)+d
 if r==0:e="black"
 elif r==100:e="red"
 elif r==1:e="blue"
 elif r==10:e="green"
 elif r==101:e="magenta"
 elif r==11:e="cyan"
 elif r==110:e="yellow"
 else:e="white"
 print(e)
 n-=1
```

Input:
3

```
4643 5913 4827 9752
5583 5357 5120 9400
2025 5475 4339 8392
```

Output:

```
black
yellow
black
```

Comment: Mind explaining what exactly what this is for, and what you're doing?

Comment: This is off topic imo. There is no "winner" and tips are more general.

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ we had many questions like that one before. they are not off topic, this had been discussed for a long time

Comment: For the close voters, golfing tips questions are perfectly on-topic here, as decided on [meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/632/are-questions-about-how-to-further-golf-a-program-on-topic-here)

Comment: Can you give us the problem statement?

Comment: Does this even work? Doesn’t the input have to be made into an int?

Comment: @Tim Although the question doesn't state it, the code is in Python 2, where `input()` is equivalent to `eval(input())` in Python 3.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of `((a*10+c)*10)+d` we can use `((a*2+c)*2)+d` to distinguish the colors.

```
 r=((a*2+c)*2)+d
 if r==0:e="black"
 elif r==4:e="red"
 elif r==1:e="blue"
 elif r==2:e="green"
 elif r==5:e="magenta"
 elif r==3:e="cyan"
 elif r==6:e="yellow"
 else:e="white"
```

Ah, but now we're just distinguishing between values from `0` to `7`, so we can index into an array instead!

```
 r=a*4+c*2+d
 e=["black","blue","green","cyan","red","magenta","yellow","white"][r]
 # or even shorter:
 e="black blue green cyan red magenta yellow white".split()[r]
```

Combining with Uriel's changes we get down to 136 bytes **(164 bytes saved)**.

```
exec'x,r,g,b=map(int,raw_input().split());print"black blue green cyan red magenta yellow white".split()[x/r%2*4+x/g%2*2+x/b%2];'*input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc1RC4IwFAXgd3/FJQitJO1uNx3SL4mIaReT1hprof5620M9fXAOh@PmcH9ZXBaeuEun3Od93p6e2mWDDbnX43Ww7hOyzf7tzBDdNM7HatUa3T2gNR@G3jNb6GZtwfMNnrpnGzTMbMxrhPE@BF795@ep8Gvcyt1U9FGMtmu8NOn297MsIpFHKYDUQYCssQJVESZEdcwEVUAHLEHJskywRAKSFYEUQkEtFH4B)

Comment: @RanvijaySingh If you don't mind putting `,` (commas) between the integers, then you can reach [115 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYxRC4IwFEbf/RWXQCwbOe@2VKRfEj2oXVRaU9bE@ettQS/nwIHvmzc3TAb3nTx1iWeW9ay9jWZe3PFUz3Y07tDqpntBqxeC3hIZ6LbGgKUnvJuejGtgI62nFdZhdHS4fGY9hvXdZzbGVJ591gdjcBvjo07S//2@i0hepWCgqjxQllgwqAqFkVLlLwsVgsqRhyw5j5CjCkEWgVKIikEpKvwC)

Answer (score 5):

For the repetition use an `exec` statement,

`map(int,` for the conversion of string input into numerals,

shorten calculating `r` with `r=a*100+c*10+d`, then put the calculations of each variable (`a`, `c`, `d`) instead of the variable,

and for the conditions use a dictionary with a `get` query.

Finally, mash everything into one line.

Final result (updating):

```py
exec'x,r,g,b=map(int,raw_input().split());print({0:"black",100:"red",1:"blue",10:"green",101:"magenta",11:"cyan",110:"yellow"}.get((x/r%2)*100+(x/g%2)*10+x/b%2,"white"));'*input()
```

Bytes saved: **121**.

Comment: Can you please add a tio link? Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I don't know what type of input OP is expecting, so I can't give an example until he does

Comment: Btw you can save quite a few bytes using `exec"..."*input()`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder right, thanks! updating

Comment: @RanvijaySingh you're welcome. what is it for btw?

Comment: You have some redundant parentheses in there (around `print`, and `(x/r%2)*100` → `x/r%2*100` etc.)

Comment: @Lynn yea, you covered it better. I just applied golfing techniques - and I'm used to python 3