# How can this code be more "golfed"?

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I found this similar [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/145391/how-can-i-shorten-this-python-code) so I'll go ahead.

I'm *very* new to code golfing, so keep your smothered laughs and throw-up emoji's to yourselves please ;). Anyway, someone recently posted a challenge (that was shortly deleted) to draw a 16x16 pixel image of the Old Man from the original Legend of Zelda, who gives you the wooden sword.

This guy:[image]

Here's my code (643 characters):

```python
from PIL import Image,ImageColor
g=ImageColor.getrgb
r=range
l=[list('0000033333300000000023233232000000003313313300000000331331330000000042333324000000042222222240000044220000224400044224222242244034424422224424433444442222444443344404422440444304440444444044400444044444404440004044444444040000004444444400000004433443344000'[i*16:i*16+16])for i in r(16)]
i=Image.new('RGB',(16,16),color='black')
for j in r(16):
    for k in r(16):
        t=k,j
        v=l[j][k]
        if v=='2':
            i.putpixel(t,g('white'))
        if v=='3':
            i.putpixel(t,g('#FFC864'))
        if v=='4':
            i.putpixel(t,g('red'))
i.show()
```

It's bad, I know. Anyway, anyone care to share some tips on shortening it?

Comment: You can definitely remove some whitespace, single spaces or tabs should work

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms isn't that incorrect syntax?

Comment: Actually it might be, I haven't used python in a while...

Comment: What is the `1` in your encoding supposed to represent?

Comment: @hyper-neutrino In the big string? it's eyes and mouth.

Comment: Is using `0` not the same though? you don't handle `v=='1'` in your if statements anyway

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Yeah, but if I wanted to change the background (an option from the original post) I would change the eyes and mouth too.

Comment: Ah. Forgot about the original spec, sorry. I see

Comment: This site may be more relevant, and is certainly more likely to get an answer, but don't forget our [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) sister site

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I considered posting there, but in the end decided to post here :)

Comment: And got some good answers too (+1) Just thought I would advertize that site :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm proposing a slightly new strategy. Instead of `Image.putpixel`, we use `Image.frombytes`, which creates an image directly from an encoded string of `RGB` values. The logic is similar to the `putpixel` version, but when implemented, it turns out to be considerably shorter:

#### 406 bytes

```python
from PIL import Image
x=b'\0\0\0',b'\xff\xff\xff',b'\xff\xc8\x64',b'\xff\0\0'
D='0000022222200000000012122121000000002202202200000000220220220000000031222213000000031111111130000033110000113300033113111131133023313311113313322333331111333332233303311330333203330333333033300333033333303330003033333333030000003333333300000003322332233000'
Image.frombytes('RGB',(16,16),b''.join(x[int(c)]for c in D)).show()
```

However, the compressed string `D` takes up almost half of the program! We can use [@ovs's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs) idea to "compress" it by storing it in a higher base (such as base 36). Now the code is almost half as long:

#### 267 bytes

```python
from PIL import Image
x=b'\0\0\0',b'\xff\xff\xff',b'\xff\xc8\x64',b'\xff\0\0'
D=int('MG8FMXO3ZANJ48JRXWYBSK3DF0HDWGJ34QP4XXAYS0EMXW3OJUIPDTNGOJGZIQZEKKSTFNJB1XQIAVDYAS8S06VLJVICO4STFK',36)
Image.frombytes('RGB',(16,16),b''.join(x[D>>2*c&3]for c in range(256))).show()
```

Finally, notice that the image is vertically symmetric. Knowing this, we can cut the size of our compressed string in half, with some overhead from the added logic. Along with some general golfing tricks, we arrive at a messy 223-byte solution:

#### 222 bytes

```python
from PIL import Image
Image.frombytes('RGB',[16]*2,b''.join(b'\0\xff\xff\xff\0\xff\xc8\0\0\xffd\0'[int('5VJ6J7FF7GD34HSPDCBV1SHKVG80MFVR3VX2RKU7WMRHBW0XZ4',36)>>2*(c//16*8+(c^-(c%16>7))%8)&3::4]for c in range(256))).show()
```

Comment: It will take some studding before I know what is going on here ;)

Comment: @dingledooper what was the process you went through to "compress" it?

Comment: @Haveaniceday The original string is in base-4. The compressed string is simply the original string in base-127. So to "compress" it we'll use a "base-4-to-base-127-converter", [like this](https://tio.run/##dZHdasMwDIWv46fQzXC8MmpbhUEgT7KNsKUuKXRJsFOaPX0m@WcbGxM29nckHYw8fyzDNOK2Hd0J3l6D6w7dMnXGPtZBNaJaoQUtqtPkoYfzCOGpaR7MC2ViaoV7OMCOMkvdK1F5F0iVUlS34XxxsHIhi7sW@sHXK9wBeavYvt@3DNy1XP0IVJfchYgumsPG0CWMNZaWKUyptP5hNNxu8AtzJAGJo6tBzBgrMAqWGBPzxRJjYcycevhAqxNjPvQf1gVZyA8qXJBdeRNI0U/vM00luGPHE/n9P2L2PHj5XdY8j5K@w7vZ1z@bldq2Tw). A similar algorithm in the code is then used to "decompress" it.

Comment: `import PIL` ..... `PIL.Image.frombytes` saves a few chars

Comment: `import PIL` does not automatically import `PIL.Image`.

Comment: You can save 5 more bytes by compressing in base 36: https://tio.run/##RYrBboJAFEX3/YrZ2PeGUmQYHVixoAZQa2IwHU3FJjIFpQkzBknUr6e2SdPNzT333NOtOxrN@75qTUOW01dSNyfTdmTa7A/lw286P664deUZIUsisJEJmwlqFwDOl6k1bgvIXbD4fcmvVfXf8qsKPuEP3Ptpt611hzCWMzHz49hPJnyUrpaTl0iyVTqXSeAuYplxufGy@Zu/XmRptHY37yOwuaBh6FmohkMmrOAJ1cczqgEToU/pIKCPfFeZlihSa9Lu9aFEbywopc75aC5I@/4b

Comment: So if you take each pixel and represent it with 2bit binary (`00` black, `01` red, `10` white, `11` tan), you get a 2byte hex 16bit number for each half line ie '00000333' becomes '003F' so the image can be shown as `003F00BB00F300F3006F01AA0528169AD65AD55AD5161515151508550055017D` in hexadecimal. In base 64 it is `AD8AuwDzAPMAbwGqBSgWmtZa1VrVFhUVFRUIVQBVAX0=`. Could more be shaved off using this method?

Comment: 44 chars to represent a 32byte code? Could you cat the 32bytes to the end of the script and read it?

Comment: @5p0ng3b0b I assume you mean the list of colors? I have found a 3-byte save for it, could you elaborate on your idea of how to shorten it?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. The image data in it's smallest form is 32 bytes (2 bits per pixel for an 8x16 image). It is how this data is stored in the code that I am suggesting could be improved upon. The data stored from the number list as base36 uses 98 bytes and the remainder of the 223 bytes is the code to display it. Instead of "compressing" the original list of numbers, if stored as hexadicimal bitmap converted to base64, the text is 44 bytes which I suppose is the limit of readable text to represent it. So would the code needed to process this data into an image be greater?

Comment: @5p0ng3b0b Using base-36 has the advantage of being easily decompressable with `int('',36)`. With base64, I think the overhead of decompressing it is just too much to actually save any bytes. Happy to be proven wrong, though!

Comment: @dingledooper you're probably tired of all the questions by now sorry :). Anyway, when you decode the base36 string `MG8FMXO3ZANJ4...` you get a big number `2053890775131...` I'm assuming that this number somehow came from my big string of numbers, but I'd like to know *how* (please). Also it could be 222 bytes if you use [16]*2 (from leo's answer)

Comment: @Haveaniceday The big number can be generated by converting the big base-4 string to base-10. The same can be said for the base-36 string. The implementation for a base conversion algorithm can easily be found or implemented. I believe I used [this](https://www.translatorscafe.com/unit-converter/en-US/numbers/39-13/base-36-base-10/) a few times.

Comment: @dingledooper is there a reason you can't go straight from base4 to base36? And I think you counted wrong.

Comment: @Haveaniceday It's hard to go from base-36 to base-4 directly because you can only perform arithmetic with decimals. Most likely you would need to convert it to decimal first.

Comment: @dingledooper Convert what to decimal, the base4 or base36?

Comment: @Haveaniceday Both would be difficult. The combination of `int(n,36)` and `D>>2*c&3` is already pretty short.

Comment: @dingledooper Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124413/discussion-between-have-a-nice-day-and-dingledooper).

Answer (score 11):

Splitting the string into rows of 16 and then using two nested loops to go over each pixel is taking a lot of bytes to do. It would be easier to just loop over the original string and use `(index%16,index//16)` to point at a specific row and column.

Also, instead of specifying a background color you can just draw every single pixel, which is shorter when using [hyper-neutrino's advice to use a list of colors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225556/62393). You can also use `#000` and `#FFF` instead of `black` and `white` (1 byte shorter each).

Bonus tip: `(16,16)` can become `[16]*2` (1 byte shorter)

Combining this with [knosmos huge save by using data compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225560/62393) and [makonede's suggestion to use as imports](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225561/62393) we can get this down to 353 bytes:

```python
import base64,zlib
from PIL import Image,ImageColor as C
i=Image.new('RGB',[16]*2)
for j in range(256):i.putpixel((j%16,j//16),C.getrgb(['#000','#000','#FFF','#FFC864','red'][int(zlib.decompress(base64.a85decode(b"Garp%d1+#J#QrG=W9sOr.gFe$difq+:dD#Fi'\\kVYS/be9`DBVETlH%2Un>#OH/p!dpQBq?eAD\\o?Ok%[FUW>EJ8;cLZ6ZbI2XaB#r3e")).decode("u8")[j])]))
i.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

Just removing some whitespace, we can get:

```py
from PIL import Image,ImageColor
g=ImageColor.getrgb
r=range
l=[list('0000033333300000000023233232000000003313313300000000331331330000000042333324000000042222222240000044220000224400044224222242244034424422224424433444442222444443344404422440444304440444444044400444044444404440004044444444040000004444444400000004433443344000'[i*16:i*16+16])for i in r(16)]
i=Image.new('RGB',(16,16),color='black')
for j in r(16):
    for k in r(16):
        t=k,j;v=l[j][k]
        if v=='2':i.putpixel(t,g('white'))
        if v=='3':i.putpixel(t,g('#FFC864'))
        if v=='4':i.putpixel(t,g('red'))
i.show()
```

(since you can inline the if statements, and putting two statements on one line with `;` saves bytes when you're in a block)

Then, you can collapse the repetitive `i.putpixel` by using a ternary `if-else`. Alternatively, you can just use a list to select the appropriate value:

```py
from PIL import Image,ImageColor
g=ImageColor.getrgb
r=range
l=[list('0000033333300000000023233232000000003313313300000000331331330000000042333324000000042222222240000044220000224400044224222242244034424422224424433444442222444443344404422440444304440444444044400444044444404440004044444444040000004444444400000004433443344000'[i*16:i*16+16])for i in r(16)]
i=Image.new('RGB',(16,16),color='black')
for j in r(16):
    for k in r(16):
        t=k,j;v=int(l[j][k])
        if v>1:i.putpixel(t,g(['white','#FFC864','red'][v-2]))
i.show()
```

Basically, for `2`, `3`, and `4`, what this does is it uses a list, `['white', '#FFC864', 'red']` and selects the `v-2`th element from it.

Comment: Ok, what's it doing now? ;)

Comment: @Haveaniceday `['white', '#FFC864', 'red']` is a list, `[v-2]` is accessing an index. It's like `a[x]`, but here both `a` and `x` are expressions. Since `v` is one of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. I use `if v>1` to only handle if v is 2, 3, or 4. Then, if v is 2, you want white, so `['white', ..., ...][2 - 2]` will give you the first element, which is white. For v=4, you want red, so `[..., ..., 'red'][4 - 2]` will give you the third element, which is red.

Answer (score 6):

You use the literal `16` 8 times.  In python 3.8+, you can write `c:=16` and then `c` the other times:

```py
i=Image.new('RGB',(c:=16,c),color='black')
```

Comment: Never forget the little things!

Answer (score 5):

Shave off 97 bytes from hyper-neutrino's answer by encoding the data with base85 and zlib:

```python
import base64,zlib
from PIL import Image,ImageColor
g=ImageColor.getrgb
r=range
l=[list(zlib.decompress(base64.a85decode(b"Garp%d1+#J#QrG=W9sOr.gFe$difq+:dD#Fi'\\kVYS/be9`DBVETlH%2Un>#OH/p!dpQBq?eAD\\o?Ok%[FUW>EJ8;cLZ6ZbI2XaB#r3e")).decode("u8")[i*16:i*16+16])for i in r(16)]
i=Image.new('RGB',(16,16),color='black')
for j in r(16):
 for k in r(16):
  t=k,j;v=int(l[j][k])
  if v>1:i.putpixel(t,g(['white','#FFC864','red'][v-2]))
i.show()
```

Comment: ah yes, garpdjqrgwsrgfedifqddfikvysbedbvetlhunohpdpqbqeadookfuwejclzzbixabre

Comment: btw you can remove `tf-` to save 3 more (`'u8'` is a valid encoding)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Turns out Python 2 doesn't have `base64.a85decode`, so this won't work. But you can still combine a b-string with an r-string, and combine that with [Leo's amazing tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225562/94066), and you've saved \$292\$ bytes.

```py
import base64,zlib
from PIL import Image,ImageColor as C
i=Image.new('RGB',[16]*2)
for j in range(256):i.putpixel((j%16,j//16),C.getrgb(['#000','#000','#FFF','#FFC864','red'][int(zlib.decompress(base64.a85decode(br"Garp%d1+#J#QrG=W9sOr.gFe$difq+:dD#Fi'\kVYS/be9`DBVETlH%2Un>#OH/p!dpQBq?eAD\o?Ok%[FUW>EJ8;cLZ6ZbI2XaB#r3e")).decode("u8")[j])]))
i.show()
```

Comment: How does this line work `from PIL import Image,ImageColor as C`? Are `Image` and `ImageColor` both mapped to C now? ...Oh, so just `ImageColor` then.

Comment: @Haveaniceday Yes, just `ImageColor`.

Comment: Upvoted this answer because it's the first to mention that you can use `#000` and `#fff` for black/white respectively, which saves two characters. Negligible, but a difference nonetheless

Answer (score 2):

## <s>215</s> <s>210</s> <s>216</s> <s>210</s> 216 bytes

By using literal characters in place of some of the Unicode escapes from [dingledooper's 222 byte solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225566/94066), we can save a byte. <s>But by encoding the program in Latin-1, we can save 7!</s>

**EDIT:** Saved 5 bytes thanks to [Jakque](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/103772/jakque)!

**EDIT:** Python by default parses programs as UTF-8, so this won't work. You would need a magic comment `#coding:l1` on the first line, so this would actually end up having to add 11 bytes.

**EDIT:** Just tested on TIO, turns out I was wrong. 6 bytes have been regained!

**EDIT:** After some more testing with Bash to try and get the raw bytes in, I was in fact correct the first time. Back to 216.

```py
from PIL.Image import*;frombytes('RGB',[16]*2,b''.join(bytes('\0ÿÿÿ\0ÿÈ\0\0ÿd\0','l1')[int('5VJ6J7FF7GD34HSPDCBV1SHKVG80MFVR3VX2RKU7WMRHBW0XZ4',36)>>2*(c//16*8+(c^-(c%16>7))%8)&3::4]for c in range(256))).show()
```

Comment: It's 215 chars, but 221 bytes in TIO. Ty for another answer!

Comment: @Haveaniceday Yes, because TIO assumes Python code is in UTF-8. This is in fact 221 UTF-8 bytes but by using the Latin-1 encoding (where all the characters in the code are 1 byte) this is 215 Latin-1 bytes.

Comment: Oh, ok. Now the shortest answer goes to you then!

Comment: you can also change `from PIL import Image;Image.frombytes(...` by `from PIL.Image import*;frombytes(...` to gain 5 bytes

Answer (score 1):

```python
import PIL.Image, base64, zlib
s = b'c$}?~T@Jt?2!nfA54&42e`bR~6Cc(PgZQCUfkXDR5YV!&&a9D%ndJ9|Ir)dDC5CqM!KF%g^YH~{$pjovNiD-9`RpnztxNF;#WPO6@aBt?_fv%3QW0r-!$ZTqrT#L(OW41F%c&RU*cng'
i = PIL.Image.frombytes("RGB", (16,16), zlib.decompress(base64.b85decode(s)))
```

Comment: Without whitespace it is **247 bytes**. Not quite as low as @dingledooper's ;)

Comment: `s` doesn't have to be in a variable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a bunch of zeros, you probably could have made something like 0x8 and then parse it to display as 8 zeros. However I am not sure if that's any shorter.

Comment: I'm not too worried about speed, just the number of bytes. Ty for the suggestion! :)

Comment: Sorry, not faster, but shorter. Mistyped that

Comment: Gotcha. If it works, I don't see why it wouldn't be shorter.

Comment: Well, a method to parse zeros might take a lot of space.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833)! As this is a [tips] question, it would be helpful if you could include an example piece of code, to demonstrate your tip to the OP :)

Comment: I tried my best but I couldn't come up with the code. This is my best attempt: https://prnt.sc/12yrc9f The code doesn't output what it was expected to output, but I hope you got the point.

Comment: @LeopardLGD my first thought was to use `bytes()` some how. For example, `bytes(8)` returns `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`